# How to check with Vimscript whether python support is enabled?

Tags: vimscript

I think it would be very nice if I can check whether current vim was compiled with python support, instead of having error message popping out every time vim is launched.

Can this check be done in vimscript?

Note that running shell wouldn't work if multiple vim's are installed and user launch one of them:

```
vim --version | grep -q '\+python\>'
```

It would be considered as a better approach if it could be checked within vimscript alone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
if has('python')
    ...
endif
```

See `:help has()` and `:help feature-list` at list item 1 and `/python`.